# glmer.nb error message: "unused argument (theta = ....)

Tags: r, lme4

I am working with longitudinal data, and trying to illustrate the idea of using a negative binomial distribution instead of a Poisson distribution, to account for over-dispersion, in the context of mixed models. I am working with the `lme4` package, and specifically trying to use `glmer.nb()`.

It was my impression that `glmer.nb()` would estimate theta - that is, that this command can be used when we do not know the dispersion parameter, and that we do not have to specify theta. I am pretty sure I got this to work earlier, and today I am unable to make it work - I do not think that I have made any changes to my code or to the packages I have loaded, but I now get an error message that seems to be telling me that I need to specify a theta.

My code:

```
ep.glmer.nb<-glmer.nb(
    count~trt*time + (1|id)+(0+time|id) 
               +offset(log(offset)),
    data=ep_long)
```

The error message:

> Error in negative.binomial(theta = 41.1203758840614) : 
>     unused argument (theta = 41.1203758840614)

I have been able to attempt a workaround, by then taking this number as the theta and using `glmer` with `family=MASS::negative.binomial`

```
ep.glmer.nb2 <- glmer(count~trt*time + (1|id)+(0+time|id) +
  offset(log(offset)),
  data=ep_long,
  family=MASS::negative.binomial(theta= 41.1203758840614))
```

I also determined that I can get a similar (but not identical) result by calling the theta from the equivalent Poisson model:

```
ep.glmer.nb3<-glmer(count~trt*time + (1|id)+(0+time|id) +offset(log(offset)),
             data=ep_long,
             family=MASS::negative.binomial(theta = lme4:::est_theta(ep.glmer))
             )
```

These workarounds are fine, and get me close enough.... but I had the impression that none of this was necessary when using `glmer.nb`.

Does anyone out there have any input as to why `glmer.nb` is not working as I expected?

Comment: my strong guess is that you have somehow defined (or loaded a package that defines) a `negative.binomial()` function with different arguments from `MASS::negative.binomial()`.  What are the results of `find("negative.binomial")` ? The package's code can probably be fixed to make this more robust ...  Alternatively, have you tried starting from a clean R session?

Comment: Adding to @BenBolker, there is likely quite a few packages which contains a `negative.binomial` function. One option is the [`GLMMadaptive`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GLMMadaptive/versions/0.6-0/topics/negative.binomial) package. If you find the culprit you can likely avoid closing and opening `R` by running `detach("package:[insert name here]", unload = TRUE, force = TRUE")`.

Comment: In fact, now that you mention it, this has already been seen, and has already been fixed in the development version of `lme4`: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/516

Comment: That seemed to do it! The culprit was indeed `GLMMadaptive`. Thanks @BenBolker and @Oliver for your prompt and accurate assistance!